# How to fix stack overflow error in visual C/C++?

Tags: c++

I am writing a file in C/C++ which generates `100000` lines of records `(name, int[5] grade, double[5].value)`. The code should generate `100000` random characters for name and integer for value. I am getting stackoverflow error. Can anyone pls help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use a recursive function to generate or process the records and do not allocate the records on the stack. Recursion can be replaced by iteration, and a stack array can be replaced by std::vector.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid a stack overflow error, don't put so much data on the stack. Essentially: don't use local variables that are large arrays. Instead, create locals which are pointers, and use `malloc()` or `new` to allocate space for the actual data... this puts the pointer on the stack but the data elsewhere.

Finally, don't forget that you must `free()` anything you malloc(), and you must `delete` anything you new, once you're done with it (and while you still have the pointers!).